# SP2010: Best Practices to use SPAudit

Tags: 2010, development, logs, spaudit

I would like to use the security audit log report of a site collection, and evaluate the entries e.g. each hour. The focuss lays on actions/events performed on the access rights on the site. Which users are added, deleted, SP groups created, removed etc. This info will be written to a custom list.

Following code can be used to retrieve the events:

```
SPAuditQuery query = new SPAuditQuery(site);
query.AddEventTrstriction(SPAuditEventType.SecGroupCreate);
query.SetRangeStart(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);

SPAuditEntryCollection auditCol = site.Audit.GetEntries(wssQuery);

foreach(SPAuditEntry entry in auditCol)
{
    // Do something with the entries
}
```

- When I execute this code every hour with e.g. a timer job how can I make sure not to miss entries which fall just on the hour, and are not picked up the next time the timer job is running?
- It's probably advisable to clean up this log file on a regular base using (SPAudit.DeleteEntries)?
- Maybe both points can be combined in one solution e.g. Take the timestamp of the last AuditEntry and delete all entries before this.

Comment: could you maybe add a few lines on the business case here? What are you trying to monitor (eg what events) and for what kind of artifacts (eg documents)

Answer (score 2):

Audit logs should be maintained as per capacity planning you have in place (Steve Goldberg gives an example of how to calculate space taken https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/Pages/Best-Practices-for-Auditing-in-SharePoint.aspx).

Only activate it where/when needed and configure trimming as soon (i wouldn't go for an hour as you could have negative impact on the database performance due to high fragmentation and frequent non-important operations) as data is no longer necessary. Another participate in this forum also shared more here [How often should the auditing log be cleared to not affect performance?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17151/how-often-should-the-auditing-log-be-cleared-to-not-affect-performance)

Data collected is always there unless you trim it, but is as well important to scope appropriately the SPAuditQuery (e.g. Request specific to a list, web, etc. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spauditquery.restricttolist.aspx)