# Track users opening files from the farm?

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, object-model

Our internal auditors have made a request to produce a regular report that shows when users access certain files.

With this in mind I was wondering - is there a way in the object model or otherwise to easily see what users are doing within SharePoint? Or is this currently not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To view who has opened documents, you can run a Audit Log report.  This is can achieved using the Audit Log reports

You go to the following setting: `Site Actions > Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Audit Log reports.`

Check [Configure audit settings for a site collection](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA010099726.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A sort of tracking is achieved via the Auditing features that must be enabled at site collection level, which also offers a quite rich object model to extract these statistics by code (had a similar answer here [SP2010: Best Practices to use SPAudit](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37465/sp2010-best-practices-to-use-spaudit)). A note of warning though - enable it selectively after proper consideration as this could get quite heavy database usage.

Alternatives would be HTTP modules to deploy your entire logic the way you want it.