# Logging document library views with HttpModule in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, auditing, http-module

I am really new to SharePoint and got an assignment of logging Document Views into an external database in SharePoint 2010... While searching over the web, I have got lot of articles on the auditing, but, most of them were referring to Audit Logs.

What I want to achieve is to have a per day threshold to each user stored in custom database, every time user tries to view or downloads a document, check whether the current user is with in the threshold, if yes, allow him to view/download the document, if not, redirect him to Threshold Exceeded page...

I have found a similar requirement in this post: [Logging document library downloads with HttpModule](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14447/logging-document-library-downloads-with-httpmodule)

However, is that the correct way to go, if not, what's the best way to achieve this...

Request you to help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

You could write a timer job that reads the Audit logs and revoked the users permissions when he/she exceeded the thershold. Abother timer could restore his access..